# Create remote control desktop with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, remote-control

I am trying to create a program with python,
I wrote code that allows one computer to connect another,
I don't know how I can see the other computer desktop and control it's running programs

```
ip = "127.0.0.1"
    username = ""#"username"
    password = ""#"password"

    try:
        print ("Establishing connection to %s" %ip)
        connection = wmi.WMI(ip, user=username, password=password)
        connection.Win32_Process.Create(CommandLine="notepad.exe /c text.txt")
        print ("Connection established")
    except wmi.x_wmi:
        print ("Your Username and Password of "+getfqdn(ip)+" are wrong.")
```

Answer (score 1):

To view the screen, you'll need to use a different protocol. I recommend RDP, because it's already installed on Windows computers. You can use the [`rdpy`](https://github.com/citronneur/rdpy) module to do this.

As for seeing what programs are running, there's probably some way to list currently running processes but I can't find it either.